# Windows Phone - How do I bring up the standard Dial Pad?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Simply put, how can I bring up the dial pad?

**Edit**

In addition to the accepted answer the `InputScope` attribute on a `TextBox` can be set to `TelephoneNumber`.

Source: [Blankenblog](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/10/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-10-inputscope-textboxes/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Actually, it seems that the `PhoneCallTask` probably doesn't do what you want.*

I'm not sure that this is actually possible without making a call as per my original answer revision. What you could do however is emulate the screen within your own application (You can bring up a `TextBox` with `InputScope="TelephoneNumber"` which will show only the numbers somewhat like the built-in dialpad), then use `PhoneCallTask` to actually place the call.

<strike>You would use a `PhoneCallTask` to show the telephone dialer interface.</strike>

```
var phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();
phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = "";
phoneCallTask.Show();
```

[PhoneCallTask on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.phonecalltask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: That's actually a quite good idea. Thank you - that will settle for now ;)
Plus: For my TextBox, I listened to the "LostFocus" event, and set the focus to itself each time focus was about to be lost. That way, plus having the TextBox focused when the application starts, makes it look like the number pad is a static part of my application :)